# Is it possible to use System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer in VS 2010? (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, text-to-speech, sapi

I am working on creating a text-to-speech engine in Visual Studio 2010 in VB.Net. I want to add some options like this: **Volume**, **Speed** and **Gender**. Many people on YouTube used *System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer*. I want to use that too, but I have Visual Studio 2010, and not VS 2013. Is there something else that i can use?

> **Note:** I already tried out SAPI.spvoice, but then I can't add settings for *speed*, *volume* or *gender*.

Comment: using your pseudonym and ancient *(!)* development tools at the same time is kinda ... contradictory ... just sayan. Install VS2015 community edition. Its free. You dont need advanced kernel driver debugging and whatnot - all of the other editions are for professionals only.

Comment: Are you not able to add a reference to System.Speech.dll?

Comment: @specializt it's possible that he could be working on legacy code. SAPI's interface hasn't changed much in the past few years, so it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @LesleyGushurst that would'nt make any sense - code does not care about the IDE. At all. You might have confused quite a few things there ... only the IDE-provided frameworks / API matter and its literally a matter of seconds to include alternative versions like the "legacy" ones you are referring to.

Comment: Are you building a TTS *application* (which causes text to be spoken) or a TTS *engine* (which actually performs the synthesis)?

Comment: Either way, the System.Speech.Synthesis namespace is available in all .NET versions since .NET 3.0.   You should just be able to add a reference in the IDE.

Comment: I'm also not sure why you couldn't get SAPI.SpVoice to do what you want, as `rate` and [`volume`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723615(v=vs.85).aspx) are explicit properties on SpVoice, and Gender is a property of the voice - one uses [`GetVoices("Gender=Female")`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723601(v=vs.85).aspx) to select a female voice, for example.

Comment: Just tested this - System.Speech is listed under the .NET tab of the Add Reference dialog in VS 2010 (VB Express).  It's surely there for any other release as well.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I don't need to install MS Speech Platform SDK!

Comment: @specializt what I'm saying is that the rest of his project might be using MSVC 2010, and that using an older version of visual studio isn't a problem.

Comment: @LesleyGushurst actually, since Microsoft constantly discovers (and closes) security holes - including those in more recent versions of Visual Studio, obsolete software **always** is a problem unless you isolate it completely.  Thats the main reason for Windows XP still being a massive problem : Microsoft doesnt close security holes anymore yet some people still refuse to upgrade ... not only are they creating personal attack vectors but their windows versions sometimes even **spread** malware without them knowing -- MSBlast, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has released Speech API as a standalone package you can download from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27226

It introduces a new namespace `Microsoft.Speech`, and here is an example of simple TTS (text-to-speech): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh378340(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: I can't install it; the installation package isn't supported by the processor type.

Comment: What specs to you have?

Comment: There are two msi's you can try in the link above. An x86 and 64bit version. You just have to get to make sure you have the right one for your processor.

Comment: Maybe I downloaded the wrong file, my processor is x86 (32-bit).

Comment: How I can install it? I located the files to E:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Speech\v11.0, and installed it, but when I open Microsoft Visual Basic Studio 2010 Express, there is no new namespace or something.

Comment: Wait, does it only works for C#? If so, I can't use it because I have Microsoft **Visual _Basic_** Studio 2010 Express, and not Microsoft **Visual _C#_** Studio.

Comment: You use VB.NET. How it can be different from C# apart of syntax? They all compile to MSIL and libraries/DLLs/Assemblies created in one are compatible with any .NET language be it VB.NET, C#, F#, you name it.

Comment: Ok, but how can I import the class to Visual Studio?

Comment: You just need to add reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx